# Regarding Tarski's High School Algebra problem

Tags: logic

Let us call a Tarski algebra a structure $$(X,1,+,*,\wedge)$$ that satisfies the 11 Tarski high school algebra axioms. Let us call a positive integer exponentiation algebra a structure $(X,1,+,*,\wedge)$ that satisfies all the identities of the positive integers with $1$, addition, multiplication, and exponentiation, plus possibly more identities.

What is the smallest cardinality of a finite structure that is a Tarski algebra but not a positive integer exponentiation algebra?

Comment: So what's the difference between your two definitions? The axioms? Restrictions on the domain $X$?

Comment: @aschepler There are identities valid in the positive integers with 1, addition, multiplication, and exponentiation that can't be derived from the high school algebra axioms.

Comment: Ah, so you mean there's at least one identity using just those operators, $1$, and free variables which is true for $\mathbb{N}^+$ but not true for some algebra. But finding a counter-model is different from having an unprovable statement. And judging from [this Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_high_school_algebra_problem#Generalisations), the answer is at most 12, but might be less if we can find an identity other than $W(x,y)$ to violate.